Partial differential equation with derivatives respect to two variables
I am trying to solve the following set of equations in the interval $0<t<1$ and $0<y<1$
$\partial_t a(y,t) + \partial_y[ a(y,t) u(y,t)]=0,$
$\partial_y[ a(y,t) \: (m+ 3 \frac{\partial_y u(y,t)}{L(t)}+\frac{3 }{2}\frac{\partial_y \partial_t u(y,t)}{L(t)})]=0,$
$\partial_t L(t)= u(1,t),$
where $m$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants.
The boundary conditions and the initial conditions are
$m+ 3  \frac{\partial_y u(1,t)}{L(t)}+\frac{3 }{2}\frac{\partial_y \partial_t u(1,t)}{L(t)}=0,$
$u(0,t)=1,$
$L(t=0)=5,$
$a(0,t)=5^b$
$a(y,t=0)=(5-y)^b$
$u(y,0)=1+y/20,$
I used the following code, but it gave me errors. I think the part I do not know how to do is the derivative with respect to $t$ in eq2.
ClearAll["`*"]
u0=1;
sol[b_,m_]:=Module[{tmax=1,dy=1/10},xgrid=Range[0,1,dy];
nn=Length[xgrid];
M1=NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1],xgrid,DifferenceOrder->4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
vA=Table[va[i][t],{i,nn}];a1=M1.vA;
vU=Table[vu[i][t],{i,nn}];u1=M1.vU;
eq1=D[vA,t]-(L'[t]/L[t]) xgrid a1+1/L[t] M1.(vA vU);
eq1[[1]]=D[vA[[1]],t];
eq2=M1.(vA (m +3 u1/L[t]+3 D[u1,t]/(2L[t])));
eq2[[1]]=vU[[1]]-u0;eq3={L'[t]-vU[[-1]]};
eq2[[-1]]=3 u1[[-1]]/L[t]+3 D[u1[[-1]],t]/(2L[t])+m ;
ic=Join[vA-(L[0]-L[0] xgrid)^b/. t->0,{L[0]-5}];
var=Join[vA,vU,{L[t]}];eqs=Join[eq1,eq2,eq3];
s=NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]]==0,{i,Length[eqs]}],Table[ic[[i]]==0,{i,Length[ic]}]},var,{t,0,tmax},Method->{"IndexReduction"->Automatic}];s[[1]]];
sol11=sol[2,0.1];
lstA=Table[{{xgrid[[i]],t},vA[[i]]}/. sol11,{i,Length[xgrid]},{t,0,1,.02}];a=Interpolation[Flatten[lstA,1]];lstU=Table[{{xgrid[[i]],t},vU[[i]]}/. sol11,{i,Length[xgrid]},{t,0,1,.02}];u=Interpolation[Flatten[lstU,1]];
x0[t_]=L[t]/. sol11;xmax=x0[1];
{Animate[Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[t],t]],{x,0,x0[t]},PlotRange->{{0,10},{0,2}}],{t,0,1}],
Animate[Plot[u[x/x0[t],t],{x,0,x0[t]},PlotRange->{{0,10},{-2,2}}],{t,0,1}]}


You haven't commented on my answer. Is there anything wrong with this answer?  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/303179/coupled-pdes-with-two-different-derivatives .

That was a great answer, I don't know why I forgot to accept it. Thanks for the note! @AlexTrounev

Thank you. For this model we need initial conditions for u as well.

Thanks for pointing this out. I have added the initial condition for u now @AlexTrounev

Any chance you know how to solve this one? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

With small modification of the code we have
ClearAll["`*"]
u0 = 1;
sol[b_, m_] := Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy];
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU;
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t]) xgrid a1 + 1/L[t] M1 . (vA vU);
   eq1[[1]] = D[vA[[1]], t];
   eq2 = M1 . (vA (m + 3 u1/L[t] + 3 D[u1, t]/(2 L[t])));
   eq2[[1]] = vU[[1]] - u0; eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   eq2[[-1]] = 3 u1[[-1]]/L[t] + 3 D[u1[[-1]], t]/(2 L[t]) + m;
   ic = Join[vA - (L[t] - L[t] xgrid)^b, {L[0] - 5}, 
      vU - (1 + xgrid/20)] /. t -> 0;
   var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}]; var1 = D[var, t]; 
   eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3];
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]; s[[1]]];

sol11 = sol[2, 0.1]

Visualization
Plot[L[t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "L"}]


Animation
lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0,
    1, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];
x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol11; xmax = x0[1];
{Animate[
  Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[t], t]], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 2}}], {t, 0, 1}], 
 Animate[Plot[u[x/x0[t], t], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, 1}]}



I am trying to plot the boundary value of equation 2 over time to se if it satisfy the boundary condition or not, but I get an error. Here is my plot Plot[(3  u1[[-1]]/L[t] + 3  D[u1[[-1]], t]/(2  L[t]) + 0.1) /.
sol11, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "L"}]

I mean this boundary condition eq2[[-1]]

It would be great to check if the solution satisfy the boundary condition

@questionerno8 Use s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}],     Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]},    Join[var, var1], {t, 0, tmax},    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}], and Plot[Evaluate[eq2[[-1]] /. sol11], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]

this doesn't give me any output!

@questionerno8 Check definition var1 = D[var, t]; before s and . Is it on place?

var1 is not defined in your answer. So I am not sure what you mean by is it on place?

@questionerno8 var1 is not defined in your code, while in my code after var we see var1. Anyway, I don't understand your question about boundary conditions. For this PDE numerical solution we should check convergence depending on dy. For dy=1/10 as in the example above we have error of about 10^-4. The maximum for  Abs[eq2[[-1]]] is about 6*10^-6 at t=0 coming from initial data. So we need to check  Norm[eqs].
