Numerical solution with both Neuman and Drichlet BC at one point
I am trying to solve the following equations in the interval $0<t<10$ and $0<y<1$.
$\partial_t a(y,t) + \partial_y[ a(y,t) u(y,t)]=0,$
$\partial_y[ a(y,t) \: (m+ 3 \frac{\partial_y u(y,t)}{L(t)}+\frac{3 }{2}\frac{\partial_y \partial_t u(y,t)}{L(t)})]=0,$
$\partial_t L(t)= u(1,t),$
where $m$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants.
The boundary conditions and the initial conditions are
$\partial_y u(0,t)=0,$
$u(0,t)=1,$
$L(t=0)=5,$
$a(0,t)=5^b$
$a(y,t=0)=(5-y)^b$
$u(y,0)=1+y/20,$
In the following link, a very similar question has been answered nicely. The difference here is in the boundary conditions. More specifically, I do not know how to add the derivative boundary condition $\partial_y u(0,t)=0$. Could someone help me with this?
enter link description here

Link you provided is wrong. Do you mean this one https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/304012/partial-differential-equation-with-derivatives-respect-to-two-variables?noredirect=1#comment748212_304012 ?

I corrected the link, thanks for pointing out! @AlexTrounev

Ok! Please, see my answer.

Using my code from here we have
ClearAll["`*"]

sol[b_, m_] := Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy];
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU;
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t])  xgrid  a1 + 1/L[t]  M1 . (vA  vU);
   eq1[[1]] = D[vA[[1]], t];
   eq2 = M1 . (vA  (m + 3  u1/L[t] + 3  D[u1, t]/(2  L[t]))); 
   eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   eq2[[2]] = u1[[1]];
   eq2[[1]] = D[vU[[1]], t];
   ic = Join[vA - (L[t] - L[t]  xgrid)^b, {L[0] - 5}, 
      vU - (1 + xgrid/20)] /. t -> 0;
   var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}]; var1 = D[var, t];
   eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3];
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]; s[[1]]];

Example of usage
sol11 = sol[2, .75];

Visualization
Plot[L[t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "L"}]


Animation
lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0,
    1, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];
x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol11;
{Animate[
  Plot[Sqrt[a[x/x0[t], t]], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 2}}], {t, 0, 1}], 
 Animate[Plot[u[x/x0[t], t], {x, 0, x0[t]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, 1}]}



I think there might be a mistake in your code. the boundary condition is $\partial_y u=0$. You have set $\partial_t \partial_y u=0$. These are different things as $\partial_y u$ is not zero at the initial condition so with your code it stays non-zero.

@questionerno8 Yes you are right. I have revised code and added new pictures.

Also, since you are putting this new boundary condition on the second element of the second equation, it means that the second element of equation 2 is not satisfied anymore.

It is ok if we use two elements on one border and nothing on another. On the other hand, I don't understand why you try to use 2 boundary conditions one border and nothing on another?

I agree that it is OK to use two boundary conditions on one boundary.

@questionerno8 Please, note, that in some problems we use 4 cells to implement 4 boundary conditions.

Thanks, but here we do not need 4 boundary conditions, right?

I also wonder if it is possible to check if the solution found using NDSolve is correct or it could be caused by a numerical error. I used the method you introduced to solve a similar problem but i am not sure if the solution contains error or not. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/305121/how-to-check-if-ndsolve-result-is-error-or-not
